# Ansicon was working, now wrong colors

Tags: rspec, ansicon

I recently installed ANSICON (x64) to colorize my Rspec output. Afterward I changed my default console property colors to experiment a bit (by right clicking cmd and changing "default" and "properties"). Now my Rspec test that are supposed to be green are the same color i changed my console text to (pinkish). The red wrong Rspec test print out bright red, and my console text has been changed back (by me) to grey, but the "green" tests are still pink!

I tried researching this out online but I cant find a post on this particular problem. Does anyone have some insight?  How can I get my green rspec test color back?

Answer (score 0):

The easiet way to reset your console properties is clearing the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. Don't forget to export it using `regedit.exe` before experiments.

Also, you may try alternative terminals like ConEmu or ConsoleZ.